# How do I create a NestJS endpoint that accepts exactly two files in addition to a string field?

Tags: file-upload, nestjs, multipartform-data, multer

Im' using NestJS 10.  I would like to design an endpoint that accepts one string field and two files (named "frontImg" and "backimg").  I have created this endpoint

```
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('frontImg'), FileInterceptor('backImg'))
  async create(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Body('title') title: string,
    @UploadedFiles(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: 'image/jpeg' })],
      }),
    )
    files: { frontImg: Express.Multer.File[]; backImg?: Express.Multer.File[] },
  ) {
    ...
  }
```

but when I attempt to submit a request to my endpoint using Postman

[image]

I get this 400 response from my NestJS server ...

```
{
    "message": "Unexpected field",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

What's the proper way to set up my NestJS endpoint to accept these two files?

Comment: Just re-upload the file to Postman again, and then call the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`FileFieldsInterceptor`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/platform-express/multer/interceptors/file-fields.interceptor.ts) to handle file uploads to specified fields. So now your controller would look like this:

```js
 @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([{ name: 'frontImg', maxCount: 1}), { name: 'backImg', maxCount: 1}]))
  async create(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Body('title') title: string,
    @UploadedFiles(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: 'image/jpeg' })],
      }),
    )
    files: { frontImg: Express.Multer.File[]; backImg?: Express.Multer.File[] },
  ) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  FYI I got a compilation error when I cut and paste your interceptor but a small adjustment, "@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
    { name: 'frontImg', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'backImg', maxCount: 1 },
  ]))" and I'm all set